# Change app icon while using tkinter (Python 3.6 MacOS)

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, tkinter

Here is a little window I made practising tkinter and I know how to change the icon next to the title as I did in code, but I would like some help changing the app icon in my MacOS dock because right now it is the python launcher icon. If anyone could help me that would be great. Also, I know there is nothing in the windows but I don't need that at the moment.

```
#Import the tkinter module
import tkinter

#Create a window
window = tkinter.Tk()

#Title the window
window.title("Welcome to ECS, we are excited to have you in class")

#Change the window size
window.geometry("400x100")

#Icon next to the title
window.wm_iconbitmap('33mm33.icns')

#Here is where I would like to be able to change the application icon

#Draw the windows and start the application
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: You have to pack it to an .app package and change the icon.icns file inside